# NX NestJS Angular, Why is Ivy complaining about modules that are not part of the frontend app?

Tags: angular, nestjs, nrwl-nx

Hello my fellow developers!

So I've been working on this app for a while now. I like to be up to date with the frameworks I use, so I regularly update when the frameworks release a new version. i.e. Angular 9 > 10. Angular 10 > 11.

So I just recently updated to Angular 11 and updated my nestjs and nx. And now when I try to serve my frontend app, Ivy seems to complain a lot.. but a.. lot... about modules that are not used in the frontend app.

```
Warning: ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils/load-package.util.js 9:39-59
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Warning: ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/optional-require.js 6:39-59
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Warning: ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/load-adapter.js 9:39-63
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Warning: ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/libs/stacks-dto/src/lib/user.dto.ts depends on '@nestjs/mongoose'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsRgbColor.js depends on 'validator/lib/isRgbColor'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsPostalCode.js depends on 'validator/lib/isPostalCode'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsSemVer.js depends on 'validator/lib/isSemVer'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsRFC3339.js depends on 'validator/lib/isRFC3339'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsOctal.js depends on 'validator/lib/isOctal'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsLocale.js depends on 'validator/lib/isLocale'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsMagnetURI.js depends on 'validator/lib/isMagnetURI'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsPassportNumber.js depends on 'validator/lib/isPassportNumber'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsMimeType.js depends on 'validator/lib/isMimeType'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsISRC.js depends on 'validator/lib/isISRC'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsIdentityCard.js depends on 'validator/lib/isIdentityCard'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsIBAN.js depends on 'validator/lib/isIBAN'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsEthereumAddress.js depends on 'validator/lib/isEthereumAddress'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsHSL.js depends on 'validator/lib/isHSL'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsEAN.js depends on 'validator/lib/isEAN'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsBtcAddress.js depends on 'validator/lib/isBtcAddress'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsDataURI.js depends on 'validator/lib/isDataURI'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsBIC.js depends on 'validator/lib/isBIC'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsNumberString.js depends on 'validator/lib/isNumeric'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsBase32.js depends on 'validator/lib/isBase32'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsBooleanString.js depends on 'validator/lib/isBoolean'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsISSN.js depends on 'validator/lib/isISSN'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsHash.js depends on 'validator/lib/isHash'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsMilitaryTime.js depends on 'validator/lib/matches'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/MinLength.js depends on 'validator/lib/isLength'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsUUID.js depends on 'validator/lib/isUUID'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsUppercase.js depends on 'validator/lib/isUppercase'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsMongoId.js depends on 'validator/lib/isMongoId'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsUrl.js depends on 'validator/lib/isURL'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsMultibyte.js depends on 'validator/lib/isMultibyte'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsSurrogatePair.js depends on 'validator/lib/isSurrogatePair'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsISO31661Alpha3.js depends on 'validator/lib/isISO31661Alpha3'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsISO31661Alpha2.js depends on 'validator/lib/isISO31661Alpha2'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsMobilePhone.js depends on 'validator/lib/isMobilePhone'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

[39[39mmWarning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsJWT.js depends on 'validator/lib/isJWT'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsLowercase.js depends on 'validator/lib/isLowercase'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsJSON.js depends on 'validator/lib/isJSON'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsISO8601.js depends on 'validator/lib/isISO8601'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsISIN.js depends on 'validator/lib/isISIN'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsISBN.js depends on 'validator/lib/isISBN'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsPort.js depends on 'validator/lib/isPort'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsIP.js depends on 'validator/lib/isIP'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsHexColor.js depends on 'validator/lib/isHexColor'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsHexadecimal.js depends on 'validator/lib/isHexadecimal'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsVariableWidth.js depends on 'validator/lib/isVariableWidth'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsMacAddress.js depends on 'validator/lib/isMACAddress'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsHalfWidth.js depends on 'validator/lib/isHalfWidth'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsFQDN.js depends on 'validator/lib/isFQDN'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsEmail.js depends on 'validator/lib/isEmail'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsCreditCard.js depends on 'validator/lib/isCreditCard'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

[9[39m3mWarning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsByteLength.js depends on 'validator/lib/isByteLength'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsFullWidth.js depends on 'validator/lib/isFullWidth'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsCurrency.js depends on 'validator/lib/isCurrency'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/NotContains.js depends on 'validator/lib/contains'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsBase64.js depends on 'validator/lib/isBase64'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsDecimal.js depends on 'validator/lib/isDecimal'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsAlpha.js depends on 'validator/lib/isAlpha'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsAscii.js depends on 'validator/lib/isAscii'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/string/IsAlphanumeric.js depends on 'validator/lib/isAlphanumeric'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/number/IsDivisibleBy.js depends on 'validator/lib/isDivisibleBy'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/class-validator/esm2015/decorator/common/IsLatLong.js depends on 'validator/lib/isLatLong'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies



Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-rmq.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'amqp-connection-manager' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-rmq.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'amqp-connection-manager' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-rmq.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'amqplib' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-rmq.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'amqplib' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/cache.providers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cache-manager' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache'

Error: ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/cookie-signature'

Error: ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/etag'

Error: ./node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/multer/storage'

Error: ./node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/busboy/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/destroy'

Error: ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/etag'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/mime'

Error: ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/mkdirp'

Error: ./node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/multer/storage'

Error: ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/send'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'grpc' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-grpc.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'grpc' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-kafka.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kafkajs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/helpers/kafka-reply-partition-assigner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kafkajs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/helpers'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-kafka.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kafkajs' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-mqtt.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mqtt' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-mqtt.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mqtt' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-nats.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nats' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-nats.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nats' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-tcp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-tcp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/core'

Error: ./node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/multer/storage'

Error: ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/content-disposition'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/express/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/mime'

Error: ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/mime-types'

Error: ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/mkdirp'

Error: ./node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/multer/storage'

Error: ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/send'

Error: ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/serve-static'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-redis.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redis' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-redis.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redis' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server'

Error: ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/sse-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router'

Error: ./node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/busboy/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/busboy/lib/types'

Error: ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/destroy'

Error: ./node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/dicer/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/dicer/lib/PartStream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/dicer/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/readable-stream'

Error: ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/readable-stream/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/readable-stream/lib'

Error: ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/send'

Error: ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/Users/user/Projects/workspace/node_modules/body-parser/lib'
```

All these dependencies are not used in the frontend app. Only in the backend app. The backend app builds, compiles and runs just fine. So why is Ivy being so up tight about it?

I am all for sharing my code with you, but that is not what my question is about.
So what is my question?

Why is Ivy complaining about modules that are not part of the frontend app? Is that a setting I need to change?

If you need more information to answer my question, ask for it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day's review of the project, I was:

- importing a class from the middleware that was using a library of the backend.
- using a library from the backend in the frontend

To fix the issues also complies with best-practices.

I have split the class in the middleware into two classes: one for the frontend, one for the backend. I have refactored the code so that the backend library was not necessary on the frontend. I ended up just fixing two files. And all the errors dissapeared.

So if you encounter something similar, double check whether or not you use some backend libraries/classes in your frontend.